# Laravel 5.2 Foreach order by date

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-5

I made a view that shows a Post and the replies to that post. As of this question, the replies are in a foreach loop and in random order. Is there a way to order the foreach loop so that the earliest reply is at the top? and the oldest reply at the bottom?.

**This the the loop**

```
 @foreach($topic->replies as $reply)
         <div class="collection">
            <div class="collection-item row">
               <div class="col s3">
                  <div href="" class="avatar collection-link">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s3"><img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ $reply->user->avatar }}" alt="" class="circle" style="width: 50px;"></div>
                           <div class="col s9">
                              <p class="user-name">{{ $reply->user->username }}</p>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                              <p>Role: {{ $reply->user->role->role_name }}</p>
                              <p>Since: {{ $reply->user->created_at }}</p>
                              <p class="post-timestamp">Posted on: {{ $reply->created_at }}</p>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col s9">
                      <div class="row last-row">
                        <div class="col s12">
                           <p>{!! $reply->reply_text !!}</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row last-row block-timestamp">
                        <div class="col s6">
                           <p class="post-timestamp">Last changed: {{ $reply->updated_at }}</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
 @endforeach
```

**TopicsController.php (Show method)**

```
public function show($theme_id, $topic_id)
{
    $theme = Theme::with('topics')->findOrFail($theme_id);
    $topic = Topic::with('theme')->findOrFail($topic_id);

    return view('topics.topic')->withTopic($topic)->withTheme($theme);

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, you can not “order a foreach loop”, if anything you would have to order the data array that you want to loop over before the loop. But this should rather happen on the database level already - write your query in a way that it returns the results sorted as you want them to begin with.

Comment: Use the `latest()` method inside of your topic query to order the replies.

Comment: No, you can not “order a foreach loop”, instead use `orderBy` while fetching the data

Comment: @Cbroe So in my phpmyadmin. Use a query like this? http://imgur.com/a/QfLGN 
EDIT:: Sorry i mean this `SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE 1 ORDER BY created_at DESC`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All Eloquent queries return [Laravel collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections). So you can use the [`sortBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-sortby) function to order your replies in the foreach.

```
@foreach($topic->replies->sortByDesc('created_at') as $reply)
```

However, a better solution would be to order your replies in the query. This can be achieved by updating your Eloquent query like this:

```
$topic = Topic::with([
    'theme',
    'replies' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderByDesc('created_at');
    }
])
->findOrFail($topic_id);
```

Comment: Gload I could help. If this solved your question, please consider marking this as the solution so other people might find this. :)

Comment: @Feudelcosine148 How did you solve this `->withTheme($theme)` with that code above?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function show($theme_id, $topic_id)
{
    $theme = Theme::with([
        'topics' => function($query) {
            $query->orderBy('replies');
        }
    ])->findOrFail($theme_id);

    $topic = Topic::with('theme')->findOrFail($topic_id);

    return view('topics.topic')->withTopic($topic)->withTheme($theme);

}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Answer (score 0):

For me the cleanest option is, in your `Topic` model, order the relations results by default using the `created_at` timestamp like this:

```
class Topic
{
    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Reply')->orderBy('created_at','desc');
    }
}
```

This way you don't need to order the collection afterwards, and let the sql do the work, resulting in a lighter code and better performance since you almost every time will need the Topics ordered that way.

This also has the advantage that the code you shared can remain untouched, but I would recommend you to eager load the relation in your controller (to avoid unnecessary queries from being performed):

```
$topic = Topic::with(['theme','replies'])->findOrFail($topic_id);
```

Hope this helps you.